# Smart pointer that manages lifetime but also copies memory on copy

Tags: c++, c++11

Given a class that you want to have recursive field in my case:

```
class SemiVariant {

 union {
  std::pair<SemiVariant, SemiVariant> pair_value_;
  int something_else_;
 }
};
```

Basically this can't be because obviously we have an incomplete type.
Using unique_ptr to admin the memory and allow the incomplete type also didn't work. I don't know if there already an existing class that will serve as `optional` but that can use dynamic memory.
`unique_ptr` are not perfect for my case because they disable the default copy constructor. Which I want to exist.

Comment: Instead of `std::pair`, maybe `std::vector` with size 2?

Comment: Using `std::unique_ptr` [works for me](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/glCCo8z97ZBY34i1).

Comment: You can't use automated lifetime management with a union type anyway, can you, since the compiler doesn't know which field you're using

Comment: @BenVoigt I thought std::vector is not supposed to work (undefined behaviour) with incomplete types, http://www.drdobbs.com/the-standard-librarian-containers-of-inc/184403814

Comment: The issue is that makes the class non copyable. I'll make it clear in the question. @0x499602D2

Comment: The question was already clear that it needed to copy contents, not share or be move-only.

Comment: @Nezquick: Note that using a union with non-trivial members also disables your copy constructor.

Comment: Can you use Boost? There's `boost::recursive_wrapper` in the Boost.Variant library that does this. And it kind of looks like you're trying to build something like `boost::variant`, so that could be worth a look as well.

Comment: @Nezquick You can also use `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: @Ben Voigt, good point. I should implement me own in that case.

Comment: @0x499602D2, I don't want more instances pointing to the same memory. I want the value to be copied.

Comment: @0x499602D2: Please read the title.  Then stop suggesting smart pointers that don't make copies.

Comment: @vsoftco: That article is four Standard versions old, now.  But it looks like incomplete types still aren't allowed for vector.

Comment: @BenVoigt ouch...for some reason I though it's from 2012 :)

Answer (score 4):

You can write your own copyable extension to `std::unique_ptr`.

```
template <class T>
class opaque_pointer : public std::unique_ptr < T >
{
public:
    // Simple construction by moving a uniqe_ptr into it.
    opaque_pointer(std::unique_ptr<T>&& rhs)
        :
        std::unique_ptr<T>(std::move(rhs))
    {
        // Print something for observation. Remember to remove it.
        std::cout << "opaque_pointer(std::unique_ptr<T>&& rhs)" << endl;
    }

    // The copy constructor you want!
    opaque_pointer(const opaque_pointer& rhs)
        :
        std::unique_ptr<T>(std::make_unique<T>(*rhs))
    {
        // Print something for observation. Remember to remove it.
        std::cout << "opaque_pointer(const opaque_pointer& rhs)" << endl;
    }

    // It needs a move constructor too.
    opaque_pointer(opaque_pointer&& rhs)
        :
        std::unique_ptr<T>(std::move(rhs))
    {
        // Print something for observation. Remember to remove it.
        std::cout << "opaque_pointer(opaque_pointer&& rhs)" << endl;
    }
};
```

Then, we can try it out.

```
struct Widget
{
    int i;
    Widget(int i) : i(i) {}
    ~Widget()
    {
        std::cout << "~Widget()" << " " << i << endl;
    }

    Widget& operator += (int rhs) { i += rhs; return *this; }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Widget& w)
    {
        return out << w.i;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "+++ Let's try the simple constructor and copy constructor! +++" << endl;

    opaque_pointer<Widget> op = make_unique<Widget>(100);
    opaque_pointer<Widget> op2 = op;

    *op2 += 2;

    cout << "Value: " << *op << " " << *op2 << endl;
    cout << "Owning: " << !!op << " " << !!op2 << endl;

    std::cout << endl << "+++ Let's move it! +++" << endl;

    opaque_pointer<Widget> op3 = std::move(op);

    *op3 += 30;

    cout << "Value: " << *op3 << endl;
    cout << "Owning: " << !!op << " " << !!op3 << endl;

    std::cout << endl << "+++ By the way, does it really manage life time? +++" << endl;
}
```

The result is like this.

```
+++ Let's try the simple constructor and copy constructor! +++
opaque_pointer(std::unique_ptr<T>&& rhs)
opaque_pointer(const opaque_pointer& rhs)
Value: 100 102
Owning: 1 1

+++ Let's move it! +++
opaque_pointer(opaque_pointer&& rhs)
Value: 130
Owning: 0 1

+++ By the way, does it really manage life time? +++
~Widget() 130
~Widget() 102
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that the copy constructor will slice the object if `typeid(*rhs) != typeid(T)`.  You could account for this by adding an additional functor for copying the object (in the spirit of `std::unique_ptr`'s deleter).  Or otherwise add a run-time check that throws an error if the types don't match.  I'm also feeling a little uncomfortable with inheriting from `std::unique_ptr` and would probably prefer an approach using composition.